# flink sql 1.12 how to get the time when window starts, and use this time caculate?

Tags: sql, bigdata, apache-flink, flink-sql

In FLINK sql1.12, I would like to know how to obtain the start time of the window and how to participate in the calculation.
This is error.
*Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.planner.codegen.CodeGenException: Unsupported call: HOP_START(TIMESTAMP(3), INTERVAL SECOND(3) NOT NULL, INTERVAL SECOND(3) NOT NULL)
If you think this function should be supported, you can create an issue and start a discussion for it.at org.apache.flink.table.planner.codegen.ExprCodeGenerator$$anonfun$generateCallExpression$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExprCodeGenerator.scala:847) ~[flink-table-blink_2.11-1.12.2-h0.cbu.dli.233.r28.jar
*
This is my sql.

```
CREATE TABLE kafkaSource (
  user_id INT,
  goods_id INT,
  exposure_pv INT,
  key STRING,
  create_time TIMESTAMP(3) ,
  click_pv INT,
  addcart_pv INT,
  collect_pv INT,
  WATERMARK FOR create_time AS create_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
) WITH (
 'connector' = 'kafka',
 'topic' = '***',
 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '***',
 'properties.group.id' = 'test_flink',
 'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
 'format' = 'json'
);

CREATE TABLE printSink (
user_id INT,
last_hour_click_cnt INT,
two_click_total_cnt INT,
total_click_total_cnt INT
) WITH (
 'connector' = 'print'
);

insert into printSink 
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN create_time >= TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, -3, HOP_ROWTIME(create_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE, INTERVAL '6' MINUTE)) THEN click_pv ELSE 0 END) AS last_hour_click_cnt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN create_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 15, HOP_START(create_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE, INTERVAL '6' MINUTE))
             AND TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 0, HOP_START(create_time,  INTERVAL '1' MINUTE, INTERVAL '6' MINUTE))
             THEN click_pv ELSE 0 END) AS two_click_total_cnt,
    SUM(click_pv) AS total_click_total_cnt
FROM kafkaSource
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    HOP(create_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE, INTERVAL '6' MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was also reported in [Having an equivalent to HOP_START inside an aggregation primitive in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668892/having-an-equivalent-to-hop-start-inside-an-aggregation-primitive-in-flink), and given the information provided there, this seems to be happening because HOP_START is being used within an aggregation.

My suggestion is to upgrade to Flink 1.13 or later, and use [windowing TVFs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-agg/#windowing-tvfs) instead of group window aggregation. This should avoid the problem you have run into.